# Why did my picture disappear?

Tags: support, gravatar

I used to have a nice picture of myself and now it's gone.

Here on the Meta Stack Overflow, my avatar picture is still the same, but on Stack Overflow, it's gone (replaced by a generic blue wavey square).

Comment: Where?  Your Avatar?  At Home?   Please be more specific.

Comment: Am seeing a dog hanging out a car window

Comment: All Gravatar pictures are failing to load for me personally right now. (Not a complaint, simply information that this is one reason why the pics sometimes go AWOL.)

Comment: Followup: it appears that OpenDNS has blocked Gravatar currently, so all OpenDNS users will be affected.

Answer (score 6):

The gravatar hashes are different (`1b1f055a9e27414280c0384c419c2649` here, `a3b6a0105b9fad65b692ab203bffaaeb` on SO), so you must have a different e-mail address in your SO profile. The e-mail has to be one that's registered with your gravatar account for your chosen gravatar to appear. Once you have your profile setup on one site, you can clone it to all the others with the "Copy Profile To Related Accounts" button on your [accounts tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152349?tab=accounts)

Comment: Interesting, the last time i posted on SO I tried entering my work email so I'd get updates as soon as possible, thinking that only had the scope of one question.  I didn't end up getting any emails though and assumed nothing happened.

Comment: That form at the bottom is for unregistered users; if you filled that out you created a separate account for that post. If you're logged in it doesn't show that form at all

Comment: Not true. If I create a question, it has a box with a checkbox to register to receive notifications on that email.

Comment: @drachenstern If it's that form his e-mail shouldn't have been changed, but maybe that's what he meant

Comment: But you _can_ change it is my only comment.

Comment: @drachenstein You're saying if you fill out that "send e-mails aobut this post here" form it changes your profile e-mail?

Comment: Ooooooooooh no.

Comment: I'm saying that's the best explanation for why my gravatar hash changed, if i understand correctly..  I know i didn't edit my profile.  And I know I was logged in the whole time.